# How to set the layout_weight of a TextView in code?

Tags: android, textview, layoutparams

I have looked around, but most of them don't make any sense. Some have a third parameter that does not exists in the Android docs, at least anymore. Anybody have any idea how to accomplish this? I have this so far:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.day_view_item, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day_hour_side)).setText(array[position]);
        if(count == 1) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.day_event_layout);
            TextView create = new TextView(parent.getContext());
            create.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(0, 30));
            create.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            create.setText("Test");

            layout.addView(create);
            count = count -1;
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

I am trying to add it to a `LinearLayout` in a `ListView`, hence the method you see in the code. One problem is that the `TextView` is not showing up when I run it. So I was thinking I need the layout_weight. Though, I am confused about one thing. What values are the width and height parameters of the `LayoutParams` constructor (dp or px)? I will also add the xml of where I am trying to add it at incase that is helpful:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/day_hour_side"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:text="12AM"
    android:background="#bebebe"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/day_event_layout"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingTop="1dp"
    android:paddingBottom="1dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" ></LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the `LayoutParams` constructors use pixels (according to the documentation).

To set the `layout_weight` programmatically, you need to use `LinearLayout.LayoutParams`. `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` does not have a third argument, as you pointer out, but the former does.

Try this:

```
create.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, 30, 1.0f));
```

[`ViewGroup.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) is a set of layout parameters for any `View` within any kind of layout (since these layouts are all `ViewGroup`s). When you have a specific layout, for example a `LinearLayout`, you can use [`LinearLayout.LayoutParams`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html) to get access to things specific to that type of layout. In this case, the `layout_weight` is particular to `LinearLayout`s, therefore you must be using the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to access this weight parameter.

You should also remove the `layout_weight="0"` from the `TextView` in your XML. If this still doesn't fix it, give your `LinearLayout` a background color and see if it's even visible at all, then edit your OP with your findings and any changed/new code.

Comment: Oh, the TextView in xml is not what I am using. Thats something else. The layout currently is fine, its what goes in the LinearLayout, but thank you very much for your quick advice. I will give it a try now. Let you know what I get.

Comment: Oh sweet, it worked. Thank you very much. Could you explain, if you can, why `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` works for `TextView`? I have never dynamically created a View to put on the screen, plus I am still new to Android. Again, thanks!

Comment: I've elaborated on the purpose of the different `LayoutParams` objects in my answer, and linked to the documentation if you need more information.

Comment: Thank you very much. You have been most helpful.